# want to hold the process till git command in subprocess.popen finishes its execution

Tags: python, git

I am beginner in python and the simple task ---I am doing-- fetch all the branches on git repository and print on console.

I see below piece of code runs fine but all time it gives me different number of branches list for the same repository,I see subprocess.popen() is non blocking so i tried to use wait() and communicate() to hold the execution but wait() is never ending the process and communicate() gives me different number of branches each time i run the code.(different than running the command on git bash)

the repositories may take different time to complete its execution. Any help to have listed all the branches.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'ls-remote', '--heads' , url],
                        stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
while proc.poll() is None:
    out = proc.stdout.readline()
    print (out)
proc.communicate()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'ls-remote', '--heads' , url],
                        stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
for out in proc.stdout:
    print (out)

proc.wait()
proc.stdout.close()
```